# how to scroll the div with the help of button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have created the div , in that i have some multiple buttons when user wants to scroll down he can click on down arrow button for scrolling up he can click up arrow button , my problem is when we click on arrow buttons scroll takes me end of the div , i want to scroll by pixels how to do it ?

```
// this is for scrolling down 
//Require jQuery
function scrollSmoothToBottom (id) {
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    $('#' + id).animate({
      scrollTop: div.scrollHeight - div.clientHeight
    }, 500);
}

//Require jQuery
function scrollSmoothToTop (id) {
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    $('#' + id).animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: i want to scroll the div on multiple click ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked over your code and tried googling `.animate()`

- https://api.jquery.com/animate/

and `scrollTop`

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop

and came up with this idea:

```
function scrollSmoothDown (id) {
  var div = document.getElementById(id);
  var howManyPixelsToScroll = 5; //change to any number
  $('#' + id).animate({
    scrollTop: div.scrollTop + howManyPixelsToScroll // not sure about this syntax
  }, 500);
}
```

If my syntax inside the animate method is right, then this would work and the complementary `scrollSmoothUp` function would just use a negative number instead of a positive number for `howManyPixelsToScroll`.

(If you had been able to post a working snippet I could have copied that code and tested these changes, but I don't work much with jQuery, so this is just my best guess, not tested.)